# What does (master *) in git mean?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am just a beginner learning git. In git bash after I've made changes to a file, the (master) changes to (master *) or (master +). Why and when does that happen?

Comment: Probably repo state - * for dirty (uncommitted changes), + for commits you haven't pushed to the remote.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this is a side feature someone has set up for you in bash. It's not part of Git itself. Git can report each of these various things, but it's up to your shell to stick that report directly into each shell-prompt.

Comment: This will be part of the output from the Prompt Script (PS) variables which are normally set up to display, obviously, the terminal prompt. In this case it has been enhanced to provide additional juicy information about the Git state when you are inside a git repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Master *` means you have **tracked** files that are changed within your git repo that have not been committed.

Untracked files (i.e. those in the gitignore) will not trigger this character to show.

---

`Master +` means you have commits to your local repository that have not yet been pushed to your remote repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, what does (master +) and (master *+) mean?

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said above - + means you have commits not pushed to remote. Apologies I missed this part of question

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! Makes sense now.

Comment: Okay, if you see master +, then do "git commit" and then "git push" to send the changes to the remote.